# notification all errors and keep different rescues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

I'm trying to **send all rails errors** as a notification, **without disturbing other rescues**.

**ApplicationController**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
around_filter :notify_errors

  def notify_errors
    begin
      yield
    rescue => e
      Notification.send_to(:admin, e)
    end
  end
end
```

**SomeController** function:

```
  def send_date
    date = Date.strptime('10/100/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
    render json: {success: true, date: date}
  rescue ArgumentError
    render json: {success: false, msg: 'Bad date'}
  end
```

I get the "Bad date" json but not the `Notification.send_to(:admin, e)`.

Comment: The rescue_from method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it easier for each reraise error? A global solution or a function?

You could monkeypatch `raise`.

```
module RaiseNotify
  def raise(msg_or_exc, msg=msg_or_exc, trace=caller)
    Notification.send_to(:admin, msg_or_exc) if msg_or_exc.kind_of? StandardError
    fail msg_or_exc, msg=msg_or_exc, trace
  end
end

module Kernel
  include RaiseNotify
end
```

I haven't tested this, it would probably have impact beyond Rails, and I think it's a bad idea! Personally, I'd just call the notification code inside the initial `rescue` clause.

```
def send_date
  date = Date.strptime('10/100/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
  render json: {success: true, date: date}
rescue ArgumentError => e
  Notification.send_to(:admin, e)
  render json: {success: false, msg: 'Bad date'}
end
```

This may be shortened with a method:

```
def rescue_with_notify error_type=ArgumentError
  *yield 
rescue error_type => e      
  Notification.send_to(:admin, e)
  [nil,false]
end
```

The idea would be to wrap what you wish to check, and respond with an array, the end of which would be the "success" flag.

```
def send_date date_string
  date,success = rescue_with_notify do
    Date.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y') 
  end
  success = true if success.nil?
  date ||= "Bad date"
  render json: {success: success, date: date} 
end
```

But this is adding complexity and *maybe* extra lines for very little in return. I'd stick with pasting the notification code into rescue clauses as and when it's required.

Comment: The monkeypatch for `raise` was what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @TheShalit Glad it could help. I got the idea from Avdi Grimm's Exceptional Ruby, it's worth a read if you get the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Raise again your exception.

```
def send_date
    date = Date.strptime('10/100/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
    render json: {success: true, date: date}
rescue ArgumentError => e
    render json: {success: false, msg: 'Bad date'}
    raise e
end
```

Comment: Really great! Is there a way to make it easier for each reraise error? A global solution or a function?